# Why is there this error while trying to integrate a function in R?

Tags: r, arguments

```
a <- 2
b <- 3
T <- 10
fun1 <- function(a,b,T) {
  return(a*(log(b+T)))
}
Answer1 <- integrate(fun1,
                     lower = 0,
                     upper=T)
```

I'm trying to find the integral of a function () =  ∙ ln( + ). It does, however, return an error no matter what I do. The error is "Error in f(x, ...) : argument "b" is missing, with no default"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend using `T` as a variable name. Your function suggests that you only have one independent variable called "t", so you should only mention that variable in `function(t)` because "a" en "b" are constants. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
a <- 2
b <- 3
#t <- 10
fun1 <- function(t) {
  return(a*(log(b+t)))
}
Answer1 <- integrate(fun1,
                     lower = 0,
                     upper=T)
Answer1
#> 2.498681 with absolute error < 2.8e-14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>